# Errors when installing angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

I have latest version of node and npm:

```
> npm -v
3.10.8
> node -v
v4.6.1
```

Getting this when installing [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Misha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.6.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-9f02c1d4
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Mishap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-9f02c1d4' -> 'C:\Users\Mishap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\Mishap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-9f02c1d4' -> 'C:\Users\Mishap\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstalling the package first solved the problem:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install -g angular-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

update your node then run the command prompt as administrator and try this:

```
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.18
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved these error by just following these steps.

1. First and very most important step, Open command prompt in Administrator mode. Reason, why I am saying it's important, because sometimes reading and writing files in generally aborted due to files read write permission available in your system.
2. If you have already installed some of @angular/cli, then uninstall it by,

   npm uninstall -g angular-cli
3. clean the npm cache as

> npm cache clean

4. Then try to install as

   npm install -g @angular/cli@latest